# How to fix MojoFailureException while using spring to build web project

Tags: eclipse, spring, exception, testing, maven

Recently I use spring STS with roo 1.2.0.M1 to build a web project. I set up the jpa and create a entity with some field and create a repository and a service layer for the entity, and then when I perform tests, it gives me the following error:

```
roo> perform tests 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WebApplication 0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) @ WebApplication ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ WebApplication ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ WebApplication ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:test-compile (default) @ WebApplication ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ WebApplication ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ WebApplication ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.8:test (default-test) @ WebApplication ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/charlesli/Documents/workspace-spring/WebApplication/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.936s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 28 20:59:59 EST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.8:test (default-test) on project WebApplication: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/charlesli/Documents/workspace-spring/WebApplication/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

And I run the mvn test in the terminal, and I get the following errors:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.614s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 28 21:06:50 EST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.8:test (default-test) on project WebApplication: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/charlesli/Documents/workspace-spring/WebApplication/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.8:test (default-test) on project WebApplication: There are test failures.

Please refer to /Users/charlesli/Documents/workspace-spring/WebApplication/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to /Users/charlesli/Documents/workspace-spring/WebApplication/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:74)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.writeSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:644)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(SurefirePlugin.java:640)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I use the following commands to build the project:

```
jpa setup --database MYSQL --provider HIBERNATE --databaseName App --hostName localhost --password root --persistenceUnit app --transactionManager appTransactionManager --userName root
entity --class ~.app.domain.DomainObjBaseModel --mappedSuperclass --persistenceUnit app --transactionManager appTransactionManager

// After running the above command, I manually add the following stuff in DomainObjBaseModel, because I don't know how to customise the roo auto generate stuff
    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(unique = true, name = "id", nullable = false, length=32)
    private String id;
// After this action, I continue run the following commands.

entity --class ~.app.domain.Application --extends com.crazysoft.web.app.domain.DomainObjBaseModel --persistenceUnit app --transactionManager appTransactionManager --serializable --testAutomatically
repository jpa --interface ~.app.repository.ApplicationRepository --entity ~.app.domain.Application
service --interface ~.app.service.ApplicationService --entity ~.app.domain.Application
```

This is the configuration of the maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

After I finish the above job, and run `perform tests` through STS roo shell, and I get the above error.

Is there anyone know that why this exception occurs? Do I do something wrong? And how to fix it?

Please help me!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One or more tests are not working.

Have a look at the files located at:  `/Users/charlesli/Documents/workspace-spring/WebApplication/target/surefire-reports` (usually the bigger files contain a problem)

There you will find the test results, and the test that is broken. The Stacktrace containing in this file will guide you to the problem.

(BTW: you can run the tests in eclipse via JUnit plugin (Package explorer, right click, run as JUnit) too, then you will see the stack trace in the IDE and do not need to search in the files.)

---

I guess, that the DB connection is not correct. But this is only a guess.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on Project-> Properties--> select project facets--> choose Java correct version which is installed on your system. Then it will works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the environment from jre to jdk as follows if it also shows compiler unavailable :

- project_name > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Libraries >
  (double-click) JRE System Libraries > Alternate Jre : jdk 1.8 >ok
- Then from Installed JRES option in Libraries select jdk 1.8
- Project > Clean
- Maven > Update

Comment: Works for me from Project-> Properties-->Java Build Path then select the Workspace default JRE (jdk 1.8) and click on the Finish button ... Click on Maven Install and the MojoFailureException no longer occurs.